# Issue in creating script that copy the sheet and update it based on form response

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to make a copy of Template in same folder when user submits the form and than update the fields in new copied sheet based on what user has submitted in the form response.

New sheet is creating successfully but response I am getting in the form is not updating in the new sheet.
Need help in finding the issue in code

error showing :

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
> at CopySheet(Code:32:63)
> at getResponse(Code:3:16)

```js
function getResponse(e){
 var response = e.response;
 var sheetID = CopySheet(response);
}



function CopySheet(response) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Q5XRV7E-m6IleX4vG2tqmJ104Osz6rb67tc8SA_1avk');
  var ssname = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());
  var folders = file.getParents();
  while (folders.hasNext())
  {
    var folder = folders.next();
    var FID = folder.getId();
  }
  var protection = ssname.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  var editors = protection[0].getEditors();
  Logger.log(editors);
 
  var TargetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FID);
  var CSheetID = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy("CopiedTemplate", TargetFolder).getId();
  var CopiedSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(CSheetID);
  var ptc = CopiedSheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var j = 0 ; j<ptc.length ; j++)
  {
   ptc[j].addEditors(editors);
  }
  
  CopiedSheet.getRange('C1').setValue(response['S.C.O Number'][0]);
  CopiedSheet.getRange('F1').setValue(response['Qty'][0]);
  CopiedSheet.getRange('E2').setValue(response['PCBA Code'][0]);
  
  DriveApp.getFileById(CSheetID).setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
  
  return CSheetID;
}
```

Edited Code :

```js
function getResponse(e){
   var response2 = e.response;
   var IResponse = response2.getItemResponses();
   var SCO_Number = IResponse[0].getResponse();
   var BOM_Code = IResponse[1].getResponse();
   var qty = IResponse[2].getResponse();
   var SID = CopySheet(SCO_Number,BOM_Code,qty);
   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are accessing the `0th` index of a null variable.

[image: output]

Use `e.values` instead:

#### Code:

```
function getResponse(e){
 var response = e.values;
 Logger.log(response);
 // var sheetID = CopySheet(response);
}
```

and upon checking the value of the response, it should look like this.

[image: response]

- Index 0 of response is the date the form was submitted.
- Index 1 is the answer of the 1st question
- Index 2 is for the 2nd question, and so on and so forth

Just use the order of the question then use it as index.

#### Sample:

If value of `S.C.O Number` is the answer of the first question, then getting the value of the answer should be `response[1]`

#### Code:

```
CopiedSheet.getRange('C1').setValue(response[1]); // answer to 1st question
CopiedSheet.getRange('F1').setValue(response[2]); // answer to 2nd question
CopiedSheet.getRange('E2').setValue(response[3]); // answer to 3rd question
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually this script is running on form side, so e.values is returning null on cloud logs which is a correct approach for Speadsheet side script. I changed the script based on what is mentioned in AppScript Documentation and it worked after those changes. Edited above. thanks again..